# Slow Ethernet Download 18.04.1 NUC8i7BEH

Tags: ethernet

The wired ethernet on my new NUC8i7BEH has very slow download under Ubuntu 18.04.1.

The fast.com site generally varies between 4 and 8 Mbit/s download speed instead of 600+ Mbit/s achieved if I boot the same machine into Windows. I have seen Ubuntu reach that speed occasionally but it's rare.  The upload speed is fine, 500+ Mbit/s.

The BIOS is up-to-date.  I've tried swapping cables, switch ports etc.

I did notice the number of RX/frame errors in ifconfig output after running the fast.com test a couple of times.

```
$ ifconfig -a

eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1492
        inet 192.168.1.9  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1997502  bytes 2160517538 (2.1 GB)
        RX errors 10332  dropped 554  overruns 0  frame 5168
        TX packets 7493707  bytes 10863936275 (10.8 GB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 16  memory 0xc0100000-c0120000

$ sudo ethtool eno1
Settings for eno1:
        Supported ports: [ TP ]
        Supported link modes:   10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Supported pause frame use: No
        Supports auto-negotiation: Yes
        Supported FEC modes: Not reported
        Advertised link modes:  10baseT/Half 10baseT/Full
                                100baseT/Half 100baseT/Full
                                1000baseT/Full
        Advertised pause frame use: No
        Advertised auto-negotiation: Yes
        Advertised FEC modes: Not reported
        Speed: 1000Mb/s
        Duplex: Full
        Port: Twisted Pair
        PHYAD: 1
        Transceiver: internal
        Auto-negotiation: on
        MDI-X: off (auto)
        Supports Wake-on: pumbg
        Wake-on: g
        Current message level: 0x00000007 (7)
                               drv probe link
        Link detected: yes
```

On Windows, `netstat -e` shows no discards or errors after running the test multiple times.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might be happening here?

Thanks in advance!

**Edit 1**
Thanks Chili - it is indeed an e1000e driver.  An hour or so ago I found this info which has "fixed" the issue:

https://forums.intel.com/s/question/0D50P00004D4D6BSAV/really-weird-problem-in-ethernet-adapter-in-nuc8i5beh-help-needed-in-debugging?language=en_US

I had the NUC's SD card reader disabled in the BIOS (the NUC is inside a cirrus7 silent case so the SD card slot is inaccessible).  Enabling it allows the Ethernet to work.  Some power-saving issue apparently.

She Who Must Be Obeyed is currently watching a movie from this box (it's a Plex server accessing a NAS), when it's over I'll restart, disable the SD card, and run your dmesg command.  As of now, with the SD card enabled, `ifconfig` says no RX errors, and your dmesg command produces:

```
$ dmesg | grep -e e100 -e eno1
[    3.019078] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    3.019079] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    3.019257] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    3.428226] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 0000:00:1f.6 (uninitialized): registered PHC clock
[    3.498216] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: (PCI Express:2.5GT/s:Width x1) 1c:69:7a:02:7b:ad
[    3.498217] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Connection
[    3.498329] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eth0: MAC: 13, PHY: 12, PBA No: FFFFFF-0FF
[    3.499126] e1000e 0000:00:1f.6 eno1: renamed from eth0
[    7.632236] e1000e: eno1 NIC Link is Up 1000 Mbps Full Duplex, Flow Control: Rx/Tx
```

**Edit 2**: I disabled the SD-Card reader and got the abysmal download speeds.  Running your dmesg commands produced exactly the same output as above.  So for now, I'll live with enabling an unusable SD-Card reader.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does the device use the driver *e1000e*? Confirm: `lspci -nnk | grep 0200 -A3` If it does, check the log: `dmesg | grep -e e100 -e eno1` As the result may be lengthy, past the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: Awesome! Glad it's working as expected. If it's all working perfectly, I see no need for more diagnostics. I hope you and SWMBO will enjoy.